# jQuery Draggable - Container size is not the good one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I've a little issue on jQuery Draggable. In my working version, the container size is blocked on few pixels, but on jsFiddle, it was in full size:

http://jsfiddle.net/586m62my/

```js
$("#dragMe2").draggable({
  obstacle: "#obstacle2",
  preventCollision: true,
  containment: "#moveInHere2",
  grid: [ 16, 16 ]
});
```

```css
#moveInHere2 {
            position: relative;
            width: 352px;
            height: 256px;
            background: #eee;
        }
        #dragMe2{
            width: 32px;
            height: 32px;
            cursor: move;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        }
        #obstacle2 {
            position: absolute;
            float: left;
            left: calc(50% - 16px);
            top: 64px;
            width: 32px;
            height: 32px;
            background: rgba(250, 0, 0, 0.6) url("images/player/skinv2/1.png");
            background-position-x: 1px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="moveInHere2">
  <div id="dragMe2"></div>
  <div id="obstacle2"></div>
</div>
```

My JS code here:

```
$("#dragMe2").draggable({
        obstacle: "#obstacle2",
        preventCollision: true,
        containment: "#moveInHere2",
        grid: [ 16, 16 ]
    });
```

But on my development version, the max size is.

I can't go over this little area.

Picture
[image]

Can you help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/ .

Comment: I've look, but i don't find solution. Heres i think is width & height related :/

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to let me find some solution. Please describe the problem you are facing in a better way.

Comment: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zli2PlpfFYo)  A little video of the problem. The area of the draggable is gosthly limited, but in reality the limitation is the grey area :/